# Is there a way to select a column that is an index in pandas?

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a df  with a fields **Name**, **Age**, **Height**.

After doing:

```
df.set_index('Name')
```

I can not longer do operations that access that column like:

```
len(df['Name'])
```

Until I do a:

```
df.reset_index()
```

Is there a better way to do this without  setting and resetting the index

Answer (score 0):

I think you can select `index` by:

```
df.index
```

Or [`get_level_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.get_level_values.html) for `MultiIndex`, but works also with `index`:

```
#select by position
df.index.get_level_values(0)
#select by name of level
df.index.get_level_values('Name')
```

So you can use:

```
len(df.index)
```

Sample:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Name':['John','Joe','Sue'],
                   'Age':[40,50,60],
                   'Height':[180,175,155]})

print (df)
   Age  Height  Name
0   40     180  John
1   50     175   Joe
2   60     155   Sue

df = df.set_index('Name')

print (df.index)
Index(['John', 'Joe', 'Sue'], dtype='object', name='Name')

print (df.index.get_level_values(0))
Index(['John', 'Joe', 'Sue'], dtype='object', name='Name')

print (df.index.get_level_values('Name'))
Index(['John', 'Joe', 'Sue'], dtype='object', name='Name')

print (len(df.index))
3
```

Comment: Actually  my problem is a little more complicated than  that.  I'm trying to do something like   groups = df.groupby(level=['Name', 'Field2'])['Name'].agg({'Count':'count'}) but I can't access the "Name" right before the agg call

Comment: Yes, it is more complicated. Can you explain more what need do with index level `Name` ?

Comment: Maybe need `apply` with custom function like `groups = df.groupby(level=['Name', 'Field2']).apply(f)` where can works with level `Name` - `def f(x):
    print (x)
    name = sum(x.index.get_level_values('Name'))
    return pd.Series([name, x['Count'].count()], index=['Name', 'Count'])`

Comment: The original problem I am trying to solve is here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41114831/convert-multiindex-dataframe-to-series